# Tensorflow: zero gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Essentially, I'm running into an issue where, when I try to update some of the variables within a scope (i.e. those in the `discriminator` scope), the gradient is always zero (I can verify this by printing them out after computing them).

This is confusing because I don't see why the loss isn't being propagated through.

My code stubs are as follows:

```
    def build_model(self):
    # Process inputs
    self.inputs =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = self.input_shape, name = "input")
    self.is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name = "is_training")
    self.targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = self.output_shape, name = "targets")
    self.target_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = self.patient_shape, name = "targets_patients")
    self.target_s = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = self.sound_shape, name = "targets_sounds")
    # Process outputs
    self.encoded_X = self.encoder(self.inputs)
    self.posteriors = self.predictor(self.encoded_X)
    self.patient_predict, self.sound_predict  = self.discriminator(self.encoded_X, tf.expand_dims(self.posteriors, axis = -1))
    self.patient_predict_id = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(self.patient_predict, axis = -1))
    self.sound_predict_id = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(self.sound_predict, axis = -1))

    # Process losses
    self.segment_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.targets, self.posteriors)
    self.patient_loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = self.patient_predict, labels = self.target_p)
    self.sound_loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = self.sound_predict, labels = self.target_s)
    self.disc_loss = self.patient_loss + self.sound_loss
    self.combined_loss = self.segment_loss - self.lambda_param*(self.disc_loss)

    self.extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(self.extra_update_ops):
        predictor_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="predictor")
        encoder_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="encoder")
        discrim_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="discriminator")

        self.discrim_train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(tf.reduce_mean(-1*self.combined_loss), var_list=discrim_vars)
        self.predict_train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(tf.reduce_mean(self.combined_loss), var_list=predictor_vars)
        self.encode_train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(tf.reduce_mean(self.combined_loss), var_list=encoder_vars)
```

As you can see `self.combined_loss` must depend on `self.patient_loss` which is found from `self.discriminator`.

My code for `discriminator()` is here:

```
    def discriminator(self, encoded_X, posterior, reuse = False):
    with tf.variable_scope("discriminator") as scope:
        if reuse: scope.reuse_variables()
        print('\n############## \nDiscriminator\n')
        print('Discriminator encode input-shape: ', self.encode_shape)
        print('Discriminator posterior input-shape: ', self.output_shape, ' (Expanded to correct size)')
        inputs = tf.concat([encoded_X, posterior], axis = -2)
        tf.stop_gradient(posterior)
        print('Stacked input shape: ', inputs.get_shape())
        h = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, 10, (5, 2), padding = 'SAME', activation = tf.nn.relu)
        h = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(h, (5, 2), (5, 2))
        print('Layer 1: ', h.get_shape())
        h = tf.layers.conv2d(h, 5, (5, 2), padding = 'SAME', activation = tf.nn.relu)
        h = tf.squeeze(tf.layers.max_pooling2d(h, (3, 2), (3, 2)), axis = -2)
        h = tf.layers.flatten(h)
        print('Layer 2: ', h.get_shape())
        h_p = tf.layers.dense(h, self.patient_shape[-1])
        h_s = tf.layers.dense(h, self.sound_shape[-1])
        print('Discriminator patient o/p shape: ', h_p.get_shape(), ' Expected shape: ', self.patient_shape)
        print('Discriminator sound o/p shape: ', h_s.get_shape(), ' Expected shape: ', self.sound_shape)
        return h_p, h_s
```

`tf.stop_gradient` is called because I do not want the gradient to flow through from the discriminator to the model that produces the posteriors.

Finally, I call my model here:

```
        feed_dict= {
          self.inputs: X, 
          self.targets: y,
          self.target_p: y_p_oh,
          self.target_s: y_s_oh,
          self.is_training: True
    }
    posteriors, cost_loss, disc_loss, patient_id_pred , sound_id_pred, _ , _  = self.sess.run([
            self.posteriors, 
            self.combined_loss, 
            self.disc_loss,
            self.patient_predict_id,
            self.sound_predict_id,
            self.predict_train, 
            self.encode_train,
            ], feed_dict = feed_dict)

    j = 0
    print('Combined-loss: ', np.mean(cost_loss), 'Discriminator-loss: ', np.mean(disc_loss))
    while np.mean(disc_loss) > entropy_cutoff:
        disc_loss, _  = self.sess.run([self.disc_loss, self.discrim_train], feed_dict = feed_dict)
        j+=1
        print(' Inner loop iteration: ', j, ' Loss: ', np.around(np.mean(disc_loss), 5), ' Cutoff: ', np.around(entropy_cutoff, 5), end = '\r')
    print("")
```

From my investigation, the code gets stuck on the while-loop as the train-step minimisation (to effectively maximise the combined_loss) simply gives zero gradients for all the variables within the `discriminator` scope. Why would this be occurring?

EDIT: I think I've localised the error to:

```
  self.disc_loss = self.patient_loss + self.sound_loss
  self.combined_loss = self.segment_loss - self.lambda_param * self.disc_loss
```

If I apply the minimisation on self.disc_loss, it works fine. But when I apply the minimisation on self.combined_loss, the operation breaks and the gradients zero. Why would this be the case?

EDIT: Tensorboard Graph

[image]

Comment: [`tf.stop_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) is not used like that, you would have to do `posterior = tf.stop_gradient(posterior)` (the returned value is the same you had but doesn't propagate gradients) _before_ defining `input`, so the gradient doesn't go further than there.

Comment: However I don't think you want `tf.stop_gradient` in any case, the three optimizers use (basically) the same loss computation just targeting different variables (so the discriminator optimizer will never affect the predictor optimizer, for example). If you stop the gradients at the beginning of the discriminator you won't be able to train the predictor or the encoder anyhow.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, true, you're totally correct - it won't make any difference anyway. That being said, I'm still completely stumped as to why the gradients aren't being propagated through. I would imagine it should given how the graph is defined, correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the gradients of the discriminator should be propagated normally, yes. There are some operations in TensorFlow that do not propagate gradients but I can't see any in your code... How are you checking that the gradients are zero, with [`compute_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients) or something?

Comment: 1) When you use `compute_gradients` you can use `apply_gradients` later to avoid recomputing the gradients with `minimize` 2) the output of `compute_gradients` is a list of pairs `(variable, gradient)`, to get the gradients you would extract the second item of the pairs 3) if you are getting `None` values in the list of gradients it is because some variable(s) has no gradient. You can simply print `self.discrim_grads` to check if that is the case for every variable or some only...

Comment: Yes, sorry - I resolved that - I was being a bit of bimbo. I think compute_gradients give a list of pairs in `variable, gradient` form. But, these are all zero for some odd reason?